# error onclicklistener on recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

i have a recyclerview and i want to when click on it receive the position and one String and sent to other activity and run it
i dont know where this code has problem.

Mainactivity

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(int i) {
    datamodel clickedItem = postlist.get(i);

    Intent detailIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
    detailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_URL, clickedItem.getmTitle());

    startActivity(detailIntent);
}
```

Adapter codes:

```
public class rrecyclerviewadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<rrecyclerviewadapter.myholder> {
private OnItemClickListener mListener;

private Context context;
private List<datamodel>mylist;

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int i);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.mListener = listener;
}
public rrecyclerviewadapter(Context context, List<datamodel>mylist){
    this.context=context;
    this.mylist=mylist;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public myholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    View view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.each_item,viewGroup,false);

    return new myholder(view);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myholder myholder, int i) {

    datamodel datamodel=mylist.get(i);
    myholder.eachitemtxt.setText(datamodel.getmTitle());
    Picasso.with(context).load(datamodel.getMimageurl()).placeholder(R.drawable.pic3).error(R.drawable.pic4).into(myholder.eachitemimg);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mylist.size();
}


public class myholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView eachitemtxt;
    private ImageView eachitemimg;


    public myholder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        eachitemimg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview_eachitem);
        eachitemtxt = (TextView)     itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_eachitem);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "id:" + getAdapterPosition(), 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                int i=getAdapterPosition();
                if (i != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) { 
                    mListener.onItemClick(i);
            }}
        });}}}
```

here there is full adapter code

on other activity i get intent.

in the adapter when testing Toast its completely works but on the mlistener and
setting id it does not work

Comment: Please paste the full codes of your `Adapter`.

Answer (score 0):

i just changed your holder class in adapter try the below code

```
 public class myholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

private TextView eachitemtxt;
private ImageView eachitemimg;

   public myholder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    eachitemimg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview_eachitem);
    eachitemtxt = (TextView)     itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_eachitem);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);


    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int p = getAdapterPosition();

        datamodel clickedItem = postlist.get(p);

        Intent detailIntent = new Intent(context, Main2Activity.class);
        detailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_URL, clickedItem.getmTitle());

        context.startActivity(detailIntent);

    }


}
```

Comment: this wont be run because you are setting Mainactivity az pakagecontext in adapter

Comment: Oops my mistake, you just need to add few more lines

Comment: i changed the the code and tried running in my application and its working now, try this now

Answer (score 0):

found it.
just need to add

```
Adapter.setOnItemClickListener(Activitymain.this)
```

to your Mainactivity